# Help explaining drug packaging, "Bromocriptine Mesylate equivalent to Bromocriptine 2.5 mg"

Tags: experimental-chemistry

API for Bromocriptine Mesylate is currently quoted by manufacturers as 2x the price per gram that we can get it already in pills and packaged in the retail pharmacy. This doesn't make sense to me... as mesylated salt form it has to be heavier than plain Bromocriptine thus would take more than 2.5mg of Mesylate to equate 2.5mg of Bromocriptine.

Am I missing something? Is Mesylate far more potent so a smaller amount is needed thus the quoted price is accurate? Over 100 quotations so far. My thinking is that the Mesylate salt form is much more highly absorbable so much less is needed. I have no idea how to do the math to determine how much of the Mesylate version to use if I want a 2.5mg equivalent to Bromocriptine itself.

Thanks

Comment: Mass ratio of equivalents of different drug forms and their price ratio are highly independent parameters, with the latter being merely business policy.

Comment: The one thing is a salt the other is not. They probably have a completely different solubility. So it might just be that. When you eat stuff, quite a bit won't go there where it should. I think from a theoretical and especially financial point of view, this cannot be solved. First you have to look at the active ingredient and the mechanism to get there. Then you look at manufacturing processes. And at the end you'll find that prices are marketing.

Answer (score 0):

Bromocriptine is a natural hormone, produced by the brain. Its formula is $\ce{C32H40BrN5O5}$, with a molecular weight of $612$.
Mesitylate is another way of naming methanesulfonate $\ce{CH3SO3-}$. It is the anion of mesitylic acid $\ce{CH3SO3H}$, whose molecular weight is $96$.
Bromocriptine mesitylate is a compound made from $1$ molecule bromocriptine plus $1$ molecule mesitylic acid, and its molecular weight is $612 + 96 = 708$. The mass of bromocryptine mesitylate obtained from pure bromocriptine is equal to the mass of bromocriptine multiplied by the ratio  $708/612 = 1.16$.

Bromocriptine must be rather expensive, and mesitylic acid should be cheap in comparison.
So bromocryptine mesitylate is expensive because of its content in bromocriptine. The price of the mesitylate ion is small with respect to the price of bromocriptine. So the theoretical price of $1.16$ g bromocriptine mesitylate must be the price of $1.00$ g bromocriptine, plus a few percent due to the price of mesitylic acid and the yield of the synthesis. Roughly speaking,  $1.16$ g bromocriptine mesitylate must cost about $20$% more than $1.00$ g bromocriptine.

Summary : Within less than $10$%, $1.00$ g bromocriptine mesitylate must cost about the same price as $1.00$g bromocriptine

Comment: It could be the price of the pharmaceutical *active* ingredient that bromocriptine mesitylate is sold instead of bromocriptine itself.  The mesylate however may modify the ADMET properties, stabilize the wanted polymorph/crystal phase in the tablet better, fulfill an other requirement of formulation chemistry better, than the neutral compound, a hydrochloride, etc.